# Is it possible to select the content of CSS psuedo::after content with just JS?

Tags: javascript

I have found posts referencing JQuery but I would like to know if it's possible to get the content string of text of a psuedo::after element on an element.

Screen shot:
[image]

If I have the element in question selected with e.g. `document.querySelectorAll('.checkout-form-error')[0];`

How can I select the string of text 'Postal code field is required.' using JS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by the [window.getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/sv-SE/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) helper.

```js
var str = window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('.mock'), ':after').getPropertyValue('content');
                  
console.log(str)
```

```css
.mock::after{
  content: "we need to get this text ye?"
}
```

```html
<div class="mock">

</div>
```